# Почему присваивание вызывает NullPointerException?

Tags: java, исключения

```
public class Test {

    Integer i;
    int j;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        j = i;
        System.out.println(j);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

`Integer i;` // Содержит null
`int j;` // Cодержит 0
Не пойму как в методе go() мы делаем аля: `null = 0` и к тому же выдает ошибку: `NullPointerException`

Comment: Вы ж делаете не null=0, а null=null в следствие чего и получаете ваше исключение, так как пытаетесь переменной присвоить null. А вот наоборот сработает. По крайней мере должно, так как Integer может хранить в себе null в отличие от int

Comment: @Dred А как получается null = null, если Integer по умолчания хранит в себе null, а int 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный код

```
Integer i;
int j;
.......
j = i;
```

эквивалентен такому

```
j = i.intValue();
```

у вас `i == null`. Вызов метода у null объекта приводит к NPE